# Signal becomes 0X00 from 0100

Tags: vhdl, processor, program-counter

I am working on a Program Counter that must be added 4 in each rising edge of a clk:

Code:

```
if_CounterSum <= MemAddr + 4;

process (Clk, Reset)
begin
    if Reset = '1' then
        MemAddr <= (OTHERS => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(Clk) then 
        MemAddr <= if_CounterSum;
    end if;
end process;
```

When simulating in ISIM,

```
After Reset is set to 0:
Initial state:
MemAddr = 0 (0000)
if_CounterSum = 4 (0100)

First CLK rising_edge:
MemAddr = X (0X00)
if_CounterSum = X (XXXX)
```

I have been working on this "simple" thing for some hours, I have tried:

1. Change the +4 line to synchronous too (Into the process) but problem kept.
2. Some other stuff that didn't worked.

How can I fix that X? I have tested other numbers instead of 4 and as I guessed all '1's in if_CounterSim where converted in 'X's after the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included all of the code, so below is a guess.

The problem is probably a result of VHLD resolution of the signal, whereby multiple conflicting drivers of the same signals as for example both `'0'` and `'1'` will result in `'X'`, but where two drivers of `'0'` will result in `'0'`.

So look for all places in the module where `MemAddr` and `if_CounterSum` are assigned, and remove those unnecessary assigns.

Comment: Works,had more than 1 process reseting MemAddr, but as the reset was the 0 I thought there wouldnt be problem. Thanks and solved :9

Comment: Think hardware. Each process generates a separate lump of hardware, and if several drive MemAddr you have short circuited their outputs together, which as `0x00` tells you, is not a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a signal outside a process you literally connect it to the right side of the arrow.
When assigning a signal inside a synchronous process you implement flip flops to assign a value to your signal on clock edges.

In your case, I suggest you put `if_CounterSum <= MemAddr + 4;` in your process. This way, the increment will be done at each clock rising edge.

```
process (Clk, Reset)
begin
    if Reset = '1' then
        MemAddr <= (OTHERS => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(Clk) then 
        MemAddr <= MemAddr + 4;
    end if;
end process;
```

If you really need the `if_CounterSum` you can add `if_CounterSum <= MemAddr` outside the process this time (because it would be wired).

Comment: I tried that too and it doesnt work, not because of itself, because another assignment was destroying the rest. Thanks you anyway!